# Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException but route is in route:list

Tags: php, laravel, exception

I'm getting the bellow exception,

> ```
> "message": "",
>     "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
>     "file": "/var/www/html/vhosts/wiseapi.hybse.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php",
>     "line": 179,
> ```

but the route is in the route:list

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmIYN.png

```
/**
     * @SWG\Get(
     *   path="/wallet/action/deposit/wallet/{id}",
     *   summary="Returns deposit data for a given wallet",
     *   tags={"wallets - action"},
     *   security={{"token": {"wallet.transactionrequest.create"}}},
     *   @SWG\Parameter(
     *     description="the ID of the deposit target wallet",
     *     in="path",
     *     name="id",
     *     required=false,
     *     type="string"
     *   ),
     *   @SWG\Response(
     *     response=200,
     *     description="successful operation",
     *     @SWG\Schema(
     *       @SWG\Property(property="data", ref="#/definitions/DepositTargetResource")
     *     )
     *   ),
     *   @SWG\Response(response=400, description="Invalid request"),
     *   @SWG\Response(response=403, description="Forbidden"),
     *   @SWG\Response(response=404, description="Wallet not found"),
     *   @SWG\Response(response=422, description="Invalid request data")
     * )
     *
     * @param string $id
     * @param Request $request
     * @param GetDepositTarget $getDepositTarget
     * @return DepositTargetResource|JsonApiResource
     * @throws UnknownCurrencyException
     */
    public function getDepositTarget(string $id, Request $request, GetDepositTarget $getDepositTarget)
    {
```

I couldn't find the solution for this exception,
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure that you use the same method type for your route as well. Because if you use `Route::get` and your method type is `post` it won't work.

Comment: I use same method type

Comment: What exact url did you get the error on?